# Reading source code, but I came across const {foo} = foo;

Tags: javascript, constants

In javascript I came across `const {foo} = foo` , what does this mean?
 Can someone explain please? I have tried everything I can do, and it is still confusing me.

Comment: It's ES6/2015 syntax. In ES5 this would be var foo = foo.foo

Comment: Appreciate greatly! That's exactly what I tried to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are puzzled about the `{foo}`, which seems to be a strange object in the left-hand side of the assignment statement, this is a destructuring assignment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

But if you are puzzled about the `const`, this is simply a const declaration: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: No worries. Btw, this is not the same as `var foo = foo.foo`, as in the comment above.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado not the same as. A const is not a var. But without ES6, that's how you'd write it.